# How to get a number wrapped in parentheses from a string?

Tags: php, regex, integer, preg-match, parentheses

I have this code

```
$string = "23 asdasdasdasd.sma(33) asda sdas asd 23 2 3 54232 23d asd";

$reg = "??";
preg_match($reg, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

I want to get this number: `33`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are calling `preg_match()` in your code and your input data only has one target number available, you can accurately use this fastest/briefest pattern:

`~\(\K\d+~`  ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GdZi0q/3)) (5 steps & no capture groups & no lookarounds)

Pattern Breakdown:

```
~        #pattern delimiter
\(       #match (
\K       #restart the fullstring match (forget previously matched characters)
\d+      #match one or more digits greedily
~        #pattern delimiter
```

*to be clear, I want to state that I my pattern assumes that the number that immediately follows the `(` WILL BE followed by a `)`.  This is what the sample input provides.

If the `)` needs to be matched to maintain accuracy, then a capture group (Tim's way) will be the next most efficient way.  All correct patterns that use lookarounds will be slower than correct patterns without.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the regex should be like this

```
$reg = "\(([0-9]+)\)";
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow.  Please always post correct methods and an explanation with the intent to educate thousands of future SO readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pattern `\((\d+)\)`:

```
preg_match("/\((\d+)\)/", $string, $matches);
```

### Demo

The first capture group would contain the number contained inside parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`\(\K\d+(?=\))`](https://regex101.com/r/5WBwBb/1)

That would match:

```
\(     # Match (
\K     # Reset the starting point of the reported match
\d+    # Match one or more digits
(?=\)) # Positive lookahead that asserts what follows is )
```

```
$reg = '/\(\K\d+(?=\))/';
```

The number will be in `$matches[0];`

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/upSWS)